# my angular application does not show anything on mobile

Tags: angular, npm, mobile, view

```
I have an angular application which I want to see how it looks on my mobile device, I use --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check, and when I open the application on my mobile using my ip from my computer it opens perfectly but nevertheless it does not show anything, I would like you to help me please
```

I have an angular application which I want to see how it looks on my mobile device, I use --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check, and when I open the application on my mobile using my ip from my computer it opens perfectly but nevertheless it does not show anything, I would like you to help me please

Comment: Did you check if your devices were using the same wifi? If yes just try with `ng s --host 0.0.0.0` without the "=".

Comment: Yes, of course, my mobile device and my computer are on the same network, I have just tried what you told me by removing the = but it still does not give me an image, what happens is that the mobile device starts the page perfectly, it opens it without problems What happens is that it does not show anything, the home page is completely blank

Comment: Can you provide more infos about the code that is suppose to be displayed please